# cada vez que cierro la terminal de wsl2 tengo que configurar el KUBECONFIG=${HOME}/.kube/conf

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, wsl

Mi primer post en stack overflow y soy nuevo en docker, ubuntu y kubernete.

Tengo instalado ubuntu 22.04 en wsl2.

En ubuntu tengo instalado un cluster local de kubernete en kind con docker.

El problema persiste que cada vez que cierro wsl2 y vuelvo a entrar, tengo que colocar el comando **KUBECONFIG=${HOME}/.kube/conf** para poder utilizar el comando kubectl; si no lo hago entonces me sale el siguiente error al usar kubectl:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿ existira alguna forma de que cuando entre no deba colocar este comando? **

Comment: Mi mejor consejo es que uses Linux como sistema base y virtualiza Windows si lo requieres. Las tecnologías que estás usando son nativas de Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varias opciones:

#### Definir la variable en el fichero `.bashrc`

Esa comanda te va a añadir directamente la definición de la variable al final del fichero

```
echo KUBECONFIG='${HOME}/.kube/conf' >> ${HOME}/.bashrc
```

Una vez lo haya hecho, reinicia la shell para que tenga efecto. Tienes que salir y re-conectarte.

Puedes comprobarlo rápidamente usando `printenv KUBECONFIG`. Caso que no te haya funcionado, tendrás que revisar quien esta manipulando esa variable. Ya que por defecto no es este su valor.

Si no encuentras solucion puedes saltar a la siguiente.

### Copiar el archivo ./kube/config a admin.conf

```
cp ${HOME}/.kube/config ${HOME}/admin.conf
```

Serviria como solucion fácil. No recomendable, te saltas las indicaciones iniciales de los desarrolladores de aplicativo.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, ahora trabajo sin necesidad de tener que configurar esas variable cada vez que entro. Gracias a tu ayuda.